# .NET Core 2.2 Render cshtml as string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this cshtml file located in this path

```
"~/Areas/Services/Views/Quotations/SpecificForms/PC/PCReceipts.cshtml"
```

I am trying to render this as a string and pass a viewmodel to it.

Currently I am using RazorLight v1.1.0 from Nuget and this is what I have tried so far:

```
var tempatePath = "~/Areas/Services/Views/Quotations/SpecificForms/PC/PCReceipts.cshtml";
IRazorLightEngine engine = EngineFactory.CreatePhysical(templatePath);
```

However when I run it, I get an error saying that I require an absolute path instead. How can I convert what I have currently to an absolute path? If I give it an absolute path, when I compile and run the program, won't the absolute path disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `IHostingEnvironment` and use `_env.ContentRootPath`:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public FooController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public IActionResult FooAction()
    {
        var tempatePath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Areas/Services/Views/Quotations/SpecificForms/PC/PCReceipts.cshtml");
        IRazorLightEngine engine = EngineFactory.CreatePhysical(templatePath);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Does it work when i publish the application as well? That is what I'm worried about